# How to display custom text below site logo image with function / filter in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image, header

I needed to display my site slogan (about four words) below the site logo image, my theme author told me to add the text after certain codes in header.php. This works but my worry is that the change will be overridden after theme update because i don't use child them, i prefer using code snippet plugin to add code to my site.

I need a function / filter that i can add to my function.php to enable me achieve this without losing the change after theme update.

Can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Install the PHP Code Snippet addon for WordPress, then you can put php code wherever you want on your site inline:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/

From the developers site:
Insert PHP Code Snippet allows you to create shortcodes corresponding to PHP code snippets. You can create a shortcode corresponding to any random PHP code such as ad codes, login validation etc. and use the same in your posts, pages or widgets.

The shortcodes generated using the plugin are easily available as a dropdown in the standard wordpress content editor as well as in widget settings, thereby giving you ease of integrating your PHP snippets with your posts and pages.

Users Guide:

https://help.xyzscripts.com/docs/insert-php-code-snippet/user-guide/

Download link:

https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/insert-php-code-snippet.1.3.2.zip